# String to utf-8 byte conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, byte

I am developing a websocket server and I need to send to the client '\x81' encoded in utf-8 and when i do:
`chr(129).encode('utf-8')` it returns `b'\xc2\x81'`.
I expect `b\x81`.
Thank you very much!

ps: i am complete newbie

Finally I have found it. I have used it bytes([129, 21, 34])

Comment: Finally I have found it. I have used it bytes([129, 21, 34])

Answer (score 1):

The output you get is correct. UTF-8 can only represent characters up to `'\x7f'` in a single byte, all characters starting from `'\x80'` will take up at least two bytes. Check any UTF-8 reference for details. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) page is a good start.

Comment: Ok, but there is any way to get a byte type that outputs '\x81'

Comment: Finally I have found it. I have used it `bytes([129, 21, 34])`

Comment: @victor: `bytes([129, 21, 34]) == bytes([0x81, 0x15, 0x22]) == b'\x81\x15\x22'` <-- is not a valid utf-8 byte sequence: `b'\x81\x15\x22'.decode('utf-8')` raises `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes, you are right. I didn't really need utf-8 byte. I needed that the output were a byte with an hex inside. I wrong when i asked. Thank you to point that!